# Finding a component using Global Id : salesforce lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am new to this. Based on our project req. I have to create unique aura:id to support dynamic appending of elements. I researched on this aura:id does not support expression. Two question

1. Can I use global id like `<a id = "{! GlobalId + '_tab' + index}">` where anchor tag will be in an iteration; so that i have a unique id for each anchor tag.
2. How can i get this unique id; the way i am using right now is

> var globalId = component.getGlobalId(); globalId = globalId + "_tab0";
>
> var activeTab = component.find(globalId);
>
> $A.util.addClass(activeTab,'slds-active');

I am getting the global id but how to find an element with global id?

Is this approach right?

Answer (score 2):

On your lightning component markup - lets say you use iteration so you have the index variable from it, and you define your GlobalId as an attribute:

```
<aura:attribute name="GlobalId" type="String" access="GLOBAL" description="my id" />
<aura:attribute name="contacts" type="Contact[]" access="GLOBAL" description="list of my standard contacts" />
<aura:iteration items="{!v.contacts}" var="contact" indexVar="index">              
    <a aura:id="{! v.GlobalId + '_tab' + index}"> </a>
</aura:iteration>
```

Now your controller should get the id correctly

Comment: how to read this in the controller? cmp.get("id generated bye global_tab0")

Comment: your code is correct - `var activeTab = component.find(baseGlobalId + '_tab' + index );` where you know already your baseGlobalId and your index.

Comment: but i am not able to find element i am getting undefined when i am trying to read

Comment: i guess compoent.find only finds aura id:

Comment: aura id can not be dynamic

Comment: You can use chrome dev tools and check what is the actual id generated on your browser

Answer (score 0):

`globalId` is unique in every component.

```
<aura:component >
```

{! globalId}

```
</aura:component>
```

2)controller

```
var id=component.getGlobalId();
console.log(id); // global id like this 345:0
```